# PHP mktime() error

Tags: php, date, timezone, mktime

I'm all of a sudden getting the following error on a site that I've done when I import an excel file to MySQL using the Excel_Reader library.

This is the error message that `mktime()` produces:

> Message: mktime() [function.mktime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone  settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the  date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' for '7.0/no DST' instead

The error is because of the following line:

```
$string = date ($format, mktime($hours, $mins,$secs, 
                $dateinfo["mon"], $dateinfo["mday"], $dateinfo["year"]));
```

I'm currently using PHP version 5.3.1. Is this script not compatible with my PHP version? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried to **READ** the error message? It clearly states what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. Relying on system's timezone settings is a bad idea and therefore you  'll need to specify a timezone using one of the following options.

You have three solutions:

1. Set a default timezone in your PHP script using `date_default_timezone_set()`:

   ```
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
   ```
2. Use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set a default timezone:

   ```
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
   ```
3. Define it as `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` file.

Documentation: [**`date_default_timezone_set()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) [**`ini_set()`**](http://php.net/ini_set)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was easy, I put `date.timezone = UTC` in my php.ini file since that's what I've been using forever and problem solved at once.